# SQL Select min(date) group by with corresponding row

Tags: sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

There are some subsets of a parent set with release date. And I want the earliest release date with the subset's no, but in a group base.

I try this:

```
SELECT Sub_No,Parent_No,MIN(DATE)
FROM mytable
WHERE other_CODE IS NULL
GROUP BY Sub_No,Parent_No
ORDER BY Parent_No DESC
```

but I get this: but I only want the most earliest released one as the 2015-02-12's Sub_No and Parent_No.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
Parent_No   (No column name)    Sub_No
07  2015-02-12  90
07  2015-11-03  88
07  2017-02-06  59
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT Sub_No,Parent_No,DATE
FROM mytable t
where other_CODE IS NULL
  and not exists (select 1 from mytable tt
  where tt.Parent_No = t.Parent_No and tt.date < t.date
     and tt.other_CODE is null)
```

If your database supports analytical function then you can use it as follows:

```
select Sub_No,Parent_No, DATE from
(SELECT Sub_No,Parent_No, DATE,  
       row_number() over (partition by parent_no order by date) as rn
FROM mytable
WHERE other_CODE IS NULL) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried the second one and it worked, as my table is lots of joined table with many lines, so it may be somehow confusing using the first one. But may I ask how could the second one work? does rn refer to the total row number?

Answer (score 0):

Only if Parent_No and DATE are unique key of mytable, then you can do  the trick like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT Parent_No,MIN(DATE) as MinDate
FROM mytable
WHERE other_CODE IS NULL
GROUP BY Parent_No
) AS Filter 
on mytable.Parent_No = Filter.Parent_No and mytable.DATE = Filter.MinDate
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! still trying this method as my table has lots of joined ones, it contained many rows..